# One column as two columns

Tags: sql

I have a table which will displays User ids in one column. I want to display that column as two columns

For example:

- In First Row, First user id in Column 1 and Second user id in Column2,
- In Second Row,  second user id in Column 1 and third user id in Column2,
- In Third row, third user id in Column 1 and fourth user id in Column2,

and so on.

Comment: why you need this .. explain the concept you will get better solution..

Comment: Add proper table definitions, SQL query you have tried so far and the DBMS you are using. What you ask might not be possible as rows are not stored in a sequential order in the the database and they need to be sorted in some way to achieve this.

Comment: HI, we have requirement to display the From User and To user in the report for an application. But in our table, the details are stored one by one i.e First User id and their action, second user id and their action, so on. So i need to display the user id in first record in column 1 and second user id in column 2  as one record. which will give meaning of Assigned By and Assigned To.

Answer (score 0):

SQL tables represent unordered sets.  There is no concept of "first userid", "second userid" etc. unless you have a column that specifies the ordering.

You can do what you want using the ANSI standard `lead()` function.  You haven't specified the database you are using, so this seems like the best answer:

```
select userid, lead(userid order by rownumber) as next_userid
from (<subquery>) s;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use row_number to create a order column and use it to join the table with itself, see this example (**MS-SQL**):

```
declare @Users as table
(
 Id int not null
,Name varchar(20) not null
)

insert into @Users
values
 (10, 'First')
,(220,'Second')
,(301,'Third')
,(999,'Last')

declare @Temp table
(
 Id int not null
,Name varchar(20) not null
,[Order] int not null
)

insert into @Temp
select us.Id, us.Name, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(order by us.Id) as [Order]
from @Users us

select *
 from @Temp t0
 join @Temp t1 on t1.[Order] = t0.[Order] + 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this solution. It works in PostgreSQL:

```
SELECT firstTable.id as firstid, MIN(nextTable.id) as nextid 
FROM [your_table_name] as firstTable 
LEFT JOIN [your_table_name] as nextTable 
ON firstTable.id < nextTable.id  
GROUP BY firstid
ORDER BY firstid ASC
```